# nltk download error13 Permission denied mac

Tags: nltk

I ran the command `nltk.download()` after typing `python3` on terminal in mac OS X. Then I am getting this error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/shreya/nltk_data/corpora/panlex_swadesh.zip'
```

This is what I got on terminal:

```
>>> nltk.download()
showing info https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/index.xml
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 1867, in run
    for msg in self.data_server.incr_download(self.items):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 529, in incr_download
    for msg in self._download_list(info_or_id, download_dir, force):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 572, in _download_list
    for msg in self.incr_download(item, download_dir, force):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 543, in incr_download
    for msg in self.incr_download(info.children, download_dir, force):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 529, in incr_download
    for msg in self._download_list(info_or_id, download_dir, force):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 572, in _download_list
    for msg in self.incr_download(item, download_dir, force):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 549, in incr_download
    for msg in self._download_package(info, download_dir, force):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 600, in _download_package
    os.remove(filepath)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/shreya/nltk_data/corpora/panlex_swadesh.zip'
```

Comment: Did the same error happen if you use python2.7 and/or python3.5?

Comment: yes. same happened with version 2.7

Comment: This happened to me when I installed `nltk` with `sudo pip3 install`. This causes the `nltk_data` directory to be owned by root. Using `nltk.download()` from `sudo python3` solved the issue as a workaround. Other solutions would be to change the permissions on the folder as in the answer below, or to install `nltk` without `sudo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, your python download process does not have the right to download files into your `nltk_data` directory. That much is clear. Since the latter is under your home directory (assuming that you *are* user `shreya`), there is no telling what may have gone wrong. You could **edit your answer** to provide more information, including the OS X version you are running, and anything else about your environment that might be relevant.

You can also try different approaches:

1. Remove the entire `nltk_data` folder, quit and restart Python, and try again.
2. Direct the interactive downloader to put the files in a different directory (see the field at the bottom).
3. Start IDLE (e.g. by typing `idle` or `idle3` at the Terminal) and run your python code in the IDLE console.

Maybe one of these will work. If not, you'll *have* to provide more information.

Answer (score 3):

Your permissions on this file are wrong. You either need to execute the script with sudo, or preferably, change the permissions by running this command:

```
sudo chmod +rwx /Users/shreya/nltk_data/corpora/panlex_swadesh.zip
```

Also, if you want to change all of the permissions in the directory, you can run:

```
sudo chmod -R +rwx /Users/shreya/nltk_data/
```