# Getting error while downloading 'stopwords' from NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am not able to download 'stopwords' from the nltk library.

`nltk.download('stopwords')`

The folder nltk_data doent have any sub-folder called 'corpora', is that causing the issue? if so how do I fix it?

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to
[nltk_data]     /Users/prasadkamath/nltk_data...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/prasadkamath/anaconda2/envs/Pk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 787, in download
    for msg in self.incr_download(info_or_id, download_dir, force):
  File "/Users/prasadkamath/anaconda2/envs/Pk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 650, in incr_download
    for msg in self._download_package(info, download_dir, force):
  File "/Users/prasadkamath/anaconda2/envs/Pk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 710, in _download_package
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(download_dir, info.subdir))
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/prasadkamath/nltk_data/corpora'
```

Comment: looks like duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908625/nltk-download-error13-permission-denied-mac

Comment: saw that question but that didnt work for me. the nltk_data is missing the subfolder 'corpora'. not sure if that is causing the permission issue

Answer (score 0):

ok figured out the solution. all I had to do was add a subfolder called 'corpora' and run nltk.download('stopwords'). I also changed permissions just to be on the safer side.